# Use of width and min-width

Tags: html, css, jqgrid, width

When writing a webpage in html, can you use two different quantitative measures for width and min_width?

For example can you use:

```
width: 90%
min-width: 600px
```

Do they both have to be the same unit of measurement (px or %) or does it not matter?  I'm trying this in a webpage but it is not working.  I am using this to minimally size a jqGrid table, but I wouldn't think that would matter.

Answer (score 11):

These can definitely work together. The width declaration will be set 90% of whatever it's container width is. The min-width makes it so that element has to be at least 600px wide.

Comment: Thanks.  This was not a cut-and-paste from my site, so I'm unsure what is causing the problem.  But you validated my initial thought.  Thanks!

Comment: @WildBill: If you provided a link we could help you further.

Comment: Worth adding that the `min-width` property always overrides the `width` property (when they apply to the same element) regardless of the order of declaration in CSS.

Comment: Try adding the semicolons ... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

It should be `min-width: 600px;`.  They can be used together and can use different units.  See an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp).  The element will not shrink to any smaller than the `min-width`, if there is enough space it will use the `width` value, so in this case 90% of the available space.

Answer (score 2):

You don't described exactly how you allow the user to change the grid size. If you use [gridResize](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#resizable_grid) then you can add additional options like

```
$("#list").jqGrid('gridResize', {minWidth: 450, minHeight: 100});
```